# IF cell in "A" column is < 0 then copy contents of "B" cell to a cell in sheet "C"

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to keep track of inventory and ordering for some products.  Once a product's inventory hits below zero (-1), I want it to add it to an "order list" on another sheet.  I've provided a 'dummy' copy of my spread sheet to show what I need.

[Dummy Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16FvjlgTy9lQegSnLf4yBvfzXyg7qT8OkyqOA-PiE4kk/edit?usp=sharing)

I have the sheet currently set up to keep up with the inventory.  Once a decal is sold, it changes the inventory to the correct number on hand in the INVENTORY page in column E.  Right now, if the inventory goes under 0, it flags the decal with ORDER in the next column.  What I want the sheet to do now is, once the inventory for a decal reaches -1 in column E, I want it to pick up the decal "name" from column A in the INVENTORY page and add it to the list on the "To Order List" page in column A.

I'm sorry if that's confusing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can have formulas on the sheet C for each item of your list which copy that item's name if its quantity is below `0`:

=IF(A1 < 0, B1, "")